# processEqualityExpression() : No expression to process! in hql

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, hql

i have a below query it executing and provide the exact result in mssql server.

```
SELECT count(Distinct(DATEPART(wk,spentDate))) FROM tblTimesheet where TimesheetStatus = 'Pending' and Approver = 6
```

I wrote the equivalent criteria for the above query below

```
Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT count(Distinct(DATEPART(wk,spentDate))) FROM TblTimesheet where timesheetStatus =:status and tblUserDetailsByApprover =:app");
        query.setParameter("app", user);
        query.setParameter("status","Pending");
        List results = query.list();
        logger.info("size"+results.size());
```

But i am getting the below exception

```
2014-11-24 12:50:48,310 ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER.reportError:33 - line 1:22: unexpected token: (
    2014-11-24 12:38:11,502 WARN  org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.processEqualityExpression:203 - processEqualityExpression() : No expression to process!
    2014-11-24 12:38:11,503 INFO  com.uniphore.timesheet.controller.ApproveTimesheetController.getTimesheet:53 - Messageunexpected token: ( near line 1, column 22 [SELECT count(Distinct(DATEPART(wk,spentDate))) FROM com.uniphore.timesheet.domain.TblTimesheet where timesheetStatus =:status and tblUserDetailsByApprover =:app]
```

How to resolve this exception.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HQL is not SQL!

The Problem here is you use native MSSQL function DATEPART, this is not an HQL function.
Read about this here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Just use a native Query like this:

```
Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT count(Distinct(DATEPART(wk,spentDate))) " + 
    "FROM TblTimesheet where timesheetStatus = ? " + 
    "and tblUserDetailsByApprover = ?");
query.setParameter(0,"Pending");
query.setParameter(1, user);
logger.info("size"+query.getSingleResult());
```

Maybe you have to change to positional parameters instead of named!

Another point:
Your output is the size of count, this would be always 1.
Change `list()` to `getSingleResult()`.